# flutter_riverpod - Accessing a `Ref` when `context` is available

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, flutter-riverpod

I'm in the process of migrating my app to use `flutter_riverpod` package. At the moment, my app is using `provider` package to manage/deal with app state.

I have a lot of static methods inside multiple utility classes that take a `BuildContext` as input. I use the context to access the provider, which allows me to read and modify the state:

```
// This relies on the provider package
abstract class SomeRandomUtilityClass {

  static FutureOr<String?> redirect(BuildContext context) {
    bool isSignedIn = context.read<AuthProvider>().isSignedIn;
  
    if (!isSignedIn) {
      return '/signIn';
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

How do I achieve this with Riverpod? From what I understand, you need a `Ref` to be able to read/write from/to a provider, but I'm not even sure if the APIs allow it.

I tried replacing the `BuildContext` parameters of my methods with a `Ref` object, but I'm having trouble getting one. All I can access is a `WidgetRef`:

```
class App extends ConsumerWidget {
  /** ... **/

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      /** ... **/
      routerConfig: GoRouter(
        /** ... **/
        routes: [
          GoRoute(
            /** ... **/
            // This doesn't work, because the method I'm calling expects a Ref,
            // and not a WidgetRef.
            redirect: (_, __) => SomeRandomUtilityClass.redirect(ref),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

An easy fix would be to modify my static methods by changing the type of the parameter from `Ref` to `WidgetRef`, but the maintainer of the Riverpod package says that [passing `WidgetRef`s is a bad idea](https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/discussions/1188#discussioncomment-2172300).

I might be misunderstanding something. Please let me know if I am.

Comment: instead of passing the ref. You just pass the value;

 final value = ref.watch(isSignedIn);    

redirect: (_, __) => SomeRandomUtilityClass.redirect(value),

Comment: make sure you use ref.watch() when reading values and ref.read when setting value or updating value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you stated, yes, `WidgetRef` and `Ref` are of two different types, thus the error.

To understand why, consider that  this:  passing `WidgetRef` is a bad idea *because* `WidgetRef`s are (indeed) linked their `Widget`'s *element*. Their life cycle are indeed tied to the life cycle of a widget, whereas the lifecycle of a provider is a different thing. In a certain way, `WidgetRef` is closer to an `AutoDisposeRef`.

But passing around `WidgetRef`s around would be dangerous since you could technically mark widgets as dirty in a way that's not meant to be with Riverpod.

Long story short, *in general*, there's a good chance you want to refactor static methods into a single simple provider, which is, in the end, just a function with a `ref` wrapper on it.

I'd highly suggest using `riverpod_annotation`, too. You'd save time *and* you'd obtain something very readable and concise (and hassle-free):

```dart
@riverpod
T yourFunction(YourFunctionRef ref) {
  final someValue = ref.watch(someDependencyProvider);

  // logic

  return someComputedValue; // Type T
}
```

In your *specific* use case, though, you're trying to implement a redirect with go router and riverpod. I'd avoid creating a simple provider like that, since it would cause the root of your app to rebuild on auth change.

That's a "deep" topic, and there are several way to do so; I've created a repo [here](https://github.com/lucavenir/go_router_riverpod) just to show off how to work around this. It's a 3rd party riverpod examples repo.

Check the `complete_example` folder, there for a full example, *or* search for older and simpler examples in other folders.